# SIze of SSIS Package and performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ssis

Can you please tell me, has the size of ssis package influence on the performance of package execution?
Now I am having a package of ~50mb size cause of included classes in script components.
Should I try to reduce the package size, or does it not matter?

Comment: Don't worry - the package size has no effect on the execution performance. It could only take a little longer to *validate* the package. It would however be good practice to remove all unused components.

Comment: Thank you very much.
How can I mark your comment as right answer?

Comment: @YuriyD: you can't. This is why people are explicitly discouraged from answering questions in comments (but we do it anyway...)